# File upload with in Spring MVC without adding any additional parameter in controller method

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, file-upload

I am using spring boot 2. My new task is file uploading. I already did it. But I am asked to do it without adding a additional parameter to controller method like @RequestParam("files") MultipartFile files[]. I want to get this from request instead of adding this parameter.

How can I solve this?

I am adding my current code following.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/uploadMultipleFiles", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody String handleFileUpload( @RequestParam("files") MultipartFile files[]){
            try {
                String filePath="c:/temp/kk/";
                StringBuffer result=new StringBuffer();
                byte[] bytes=null;
                result.append("Uploading of File(s) ");

                for (int i=0;i<files.length;i++) {
                    if (!files[i].isEmpty()) {
                        bytes = files[i].getBytes();
                        BufferedOutputStream stream = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File(filePath+files[i].getOriginalFilename())));
                        stream.write(bytes);
                        stream.close();

                       result.append(files[i].getOriginalFilename() + " Ok. ") ;
                    }
                    else
                        result.append( files[i].getOriginalFilename() + " Failed. ");

            }
                return result.toString();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                return "Error Occured while uploading files." + " => " + e.getMessage();
            }

    }
```

Comment: So you want to make it more complex instead of easier...

Answer (score 0):

You can get files from HttpRequest:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/uploadMultipleFiles", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String handleFileUpload(HttpRequest request){

        MultipartHttpServletRequest multipartRequest = (MultipartHttpServletRequest) request;

       Map<String, MultipartFile> yourFiles = multipartRequest.getFileMap();

        return "All is Ok!";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

My sample code.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/multiple/upload", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody String test(@RequestParam(value = "files[]") List<MultipartFile> files,
        HttpServletRequest req) {

    MultipartFileWriter writer = new MultipartFileWriter();
    String folderPath = "/file/";

    for (MultipartFile file : files) {
        writer.writeFile(file, folderPath, req);
    }

    return "success";
}
```